# Print console output to text file

Tags: python, console, text-files

```
import random
import time
import sys


# variable declaration

user_cave=0
cave=0
result=""
playagain="Y"

while playagain=="Y" or playagain=="y":
    fo=open("save_game",'w')

    print("\nYou are in the Kingdom of Dragons.\nIn front of you, you see two caves.\nIn one cave, the dragon is friendly and will share his treasure with you.\nThe other dragon is hungry and will eat you on sight!\nGood luck on your journey\n")
    while True: # including while true because program should till break

        try: # repeat till user give correct value
            user_cave=int(input("Please select cave 1,2,3,4 or 5 : "))
            if user_cave>0 and user_cave<6:
                break

            else:
                continue

        except:
            ""
        

    #create random number to differentiate
    cave=random.randrange(1,3)

    # Bad dragon
    if cave==1:
        result="Gobbles you down!"
    # Good Dragon
    elif cave==2:
        result="Greets you before share his treasure!"

    print("\nYou approach the cave....",user_cave)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print("A large dragon jumps out in front of you!")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print("HE OPENS HIS JAWS AND.....\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(result,"\n")

    playagain=input("Do you want to play again ? [y/n] : ")

sys.stdout = open("File location",'w')

sys.stdout.close()
```

I want to print all the print statement outputs into a text file. If user selects to play the game again without closing the program the file needs to be appended, but if the user closes and runs the program again the file needs to be overwritten with the new outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save all the print statements into a text file then, you can copy the things you want to save in the file and store them in a variable and then write them in the text file. For example, I edited your code to this:

```
import time
import sys

# variable declaration

user_cave = 0
cave = 0
result = ""
playagain = "Y"

while playagain == "Y" or playagain == "y":
    f = open("Dragon Game.txt", 'w')
    f.write("")
    print(
        "\nYou are in the Kingdom of Dragons.\nIn front of you, you see two caves.\nIn one cave, the dragon is friendly and will share his treasure with you.\nThe other dragon is hungry and will eat you on sight!\nGood luck on your journey\n")
    while True:  # including while true because program should till break

        try:  # repeat till user give correct value
            user_cave = int(input("Please select cave 1,2,3,4 or 5 : "))
            if user_cave > 0 and user_cave < 6:
                break

            else:
                continue

        except:
            ""

    # create random number to differentiate
    cave = random.randrange(1, 3)

    # Bad dragon
    if cave == 1:
        result = "Gobbles you down!"
    # Good Dragon
    elif cave == 2:
        result = "Greets you before share his treasure!"
    txt = f"\nYou are in the Kingdom of Dragons.\nIn front of you, you see two caves.\nIn one cave, the dragon is friendly and will share his treasure with you.\nThe other dragon is hungry and will eat you on sight!\nGood luck on your journey\nYou approach the cave....{str(user_cave)}\nA large dragon jumps out in front of you!\nHE OPENS HIS JAWS AND.....\n{result}"
    f = open("Dragon Game.txt", "a")
    f.write(txt)
    print("\nYou approach the cave.... " + str(user_cave))
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print("A large dragon jumps out in front of you!")
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print("HE OPENS HIS JAWS AND.....\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(result, "\n")

    playagain = input("Do you want to play again ? [y/n] : ")
```

Just, before running this file, you have to create a file named `Dragon Game.txt` It's compulsory to run the code.

Comment: The text you want to be saved is stored in a "txt" variable and that variable is written in the file. And it re-writes the file when a new game is started

Answer (score 1):

I think so, create a new file name xx_time each game

```
now_time = time.strftime("_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S]", time.localtime())
# All info about the game is contained in this file
file_path = os.path.join("/your_folder", "game_file{}.txt".format(now_time))
```

Create a function to print and write info to txt file

```
def print_and_write(file_object, info):
    print(info)
    file_object.write(info)
```

Comment: But then you'd have too many files in one place which could be a lot of space-occupying.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand what you mean, I thought you needed to keep all your history